# Ajax Search Lite: Customize Autoscroll

Tags: plugins, ajax, css

I just installed Ajax search lite and I'm very convinced about the plugin. But I have two questions regarding to the autoscroll function:

1. How can I set down the speed of the auto scroll effect?
2. And I want to say "Do not scroll so far" - Is there any possible solution to set the scroll "index" lower?

Greetings and Thank You!